# Grails 2.5.3 controller integration test gets NullPointerException when an ation is @Transactional

Tags: grails, transactions, integration-testing, spock

I have a controller were only the save action is marked as @Transactional.

I need to do some integration tests on the controller (yes not unit) and I was getting NullPointerException on the test on the controller.save() line.

When I removed the @Transactional from the save action, the test worked OK.

Should I add something to the test to correctly handle the transactional action? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Try to import `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`instead of `grails.transaction.Transactional`

Comment: zfChaos I've read that with the spring transactional class the test works but the transactional behavior in the controller is lost at runtime. I'll put the reference here.